# Shapefile for Petrol Fueling stations across USA

Tags: data-request, usa, geocoding

I am trying to find a shapefile or csv/kml/kmz file with all of USA's vehicular fueling stations. All I have found thus far is E85 (alternative fuel stations) from energy.gov (https://energy.gov/maps/alternative-fueling-station-locator).

Does anybody know where I can find other fuel types (such as E87, 89, 95 etc), i.e. just regular gas stations?

Comment: Octane as in Regular (87) Regular Mid (89), Premium (91) is not the same rating in North America as in Europe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating for Data this api has fuel type http://www.mygasfeed.com/keys/api

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I do not think that there is a data set with this information meaning that you will have to construct one yourself. This can be relatively easy using the the MMQGIS plugin to turn street address into point data. Here is a link to how to use MMQGIS. Good luck! https://www.gislounge.com/how-to-geocode-addresses-using-qgis/

Comment: MMQGIS plugin is an awesome plugin, the geocoding app is great and will produce +95% complete addresses to points in my experience using it.

Comment: doesnt the MMQGIS plugin limits you to 2k addresses?

Comment: He could run twice and then merge data sets

Answer (score 3):

An option may be to scrape websites that contain the location information, these are the one's I'm familiar with:

[List of filling stations in North America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filling_stations_in_North_America)

[All Gas Stations USA](http://www.allgasstations.com/)

[Exxon Mobile Stations List](http://www.exxonmobilstations.com/station-locations/united-states)

[List of Ethanol Free Gas Stations](http://pure-gas.org/)

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, your probably going to have to roll your own. Scraping for data is one way (also already mentioned) but there are some existing datasets that you can leverage to make your life easier.
These two searches in ESRI's open data portal look fruitful:
[Search Open Data ArcGiS for "Gas"](http://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=gas%20) and [Search Open Data ArcGIS for "Gas Service Areas"](http://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=gas%20service%20areas).

Here's two states right off the bat to lessen the scraping work: [Gas Stations in North Carolina](http://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/nconemap::gas-stations) and two for New Jersey: [Gas Service Stations in NJ](http://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/488f8af430364adbaa2b91d3869a7c1d_2), [New Jersey Gasoline Service Stations](http://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/newjersey::new-jersey-gasoline-service-stations). As well as some data for a region [Convenience Stores Gas Stations - UTC GEODATA Portal](http://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/8c0fea054dbc4d8bbab6a4aa2db7f954_0).

Looking at locality emergency data is another route to find data; [New Orleans Gas Stations](http://portal-nolagis.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/gas-stations/data) was in their emergency datasets.

I'd also recommend checking out the EPA's TRI (Toxic Release Inventory), as well as individual states internal departments that deal with environment. For another example, Virginia releases data about buried container leaks, which I've found almost always are gas tanks below gas stations.
Energy.gov and its related websites over some data, but it all looks like you have to do legwork there too: 
Viewing EIA's "Other Resources" option under each state's profile is worth a look too; [here's Virginia's "Other Resources"](https://www.eia.gov/state/other.php?sid=VA).

[EIA's methodology for Gas/Diesel prices](https://www.eia.gov/petroleum/gasdiesel/learnmore.php) should have the locations, but I don't see them off hand. May also be worthwhile to simply reach out to them: InfoCtr@eia.gov.
Also: [Alternative Fuels Data Center](https://www.afdc.energy.gov/data_download/) and [Alterative Fueling Station Locator](https://www.afdc.energy.gov/locator/stations/)

Lastly, [Does Waze do this?](https://wiki.waze.com/wiki/Places/Gas_Station)?
Also here is the methodology for [Mapping the Best Places to Find the Lowest Gas Prices](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0711/feature2.html)